# Have unique URLs on the ad site

Tags: url-rewriting, ads

For some time now I have had a problem with an ad site that I am developing with wordpréss. I am unable to generate unique pages with the post id as in this example website:
... Acer-nitro-17-gtx-1650-pid10198770
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the post ID in the URL? WordPress doesn't need that for routing. Or are you going to change the routing too to just use the post ID from the URL?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. It's for SEO, so I need it so as not to have duplicate content from potential users of the site. For example: two advertisements could have the same title like: house for sale in Paris. And to solve this problem putting the id will make the url of the two publications unique.

Comment: OK. WordPress already requires posts have unique slugs though.